# How to stop sprite size changes from stopping collision detection in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, phaser-framework

I am developing a small JavaScript game with Phaser and I have a sprite that changes its size at certain points. It does this with the [`sprite.body.setSize`](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#setSize) method. However, it looks like the sprite stops colliding with objects that it should be colliding with when it is changing size. I understand why it does this, since the sprite's boundaries are in a state of flux during a change of size, but I'm afraid my user can take advantage of this problem and move through walls. I'm not sure how to get the sprite to be responsive to collisions while it's in the process of changing size. Is there a way to prevent this?

**Edit at Supamiu's request:**

[Here is a quick example](http://cl.ly/3h1m3t3z2n0A) of what I'm trying to do in my game. Also, here is the source code for that example.

```
// Global constants
var GAME_WIDTH = 800;
var GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

var TEXT_X_POS = 150;
var TEXT_Y_POS = 50;

var PHASER_DUDE_WIDTH = 27;
var PHASER_DUDE_HEIGHT = 40;

var MASTER_WIDTH = 57;
var MASTER_HEIGHT = 77;

var SPRITE_X_POS = 200;
var SPRITE_Y_POS = 400;

var SPRITE_GRAVITY = 300;

var LEFT_VELOCITY = -300;
var RIGHT_VELOCITY = 300;
var JUMP_VELOCITY = -300;
var STOPPED = 0;

var WALL_X_POS = 500;
var WALL_Y_POS = 300;

// Global variables
var sprite;
var wall;
var cursors;

var game = new Phaser.Game(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, Phaser.AUTO, "game", {preload: preload, create: create, update: update});

function preload () {
    game.load.image("master", "sprites/master.png");
    game.load.image("phaser dude", "sprites/phaser_dude.png");
    game.load.image("wall", "sprites/wall.png");
}

function create () {
    game.add.text(TEXT_X_POS, TEXT_Y_POS, "Use the cursor keys to jump and move", {fontSize: "16px", fill: "white"});

    sprite = game.add.sprite(SPRITE_X_POS, SPRITE_Y_POS, "master");
    game.physics.arcade.enable(sprite);
    sprite.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    sprite.body.gravity.y = SPRITE_GRAVITY;

    wall = game.add.sprite(WALL_X_POS, WALL_Y_POS, "wall");
    game.physics.arcade.enable(wall);
    wall.body.immovable = true;

    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function update () {
    game.physics.arcade.collide(sprite, wall);

    sprite.body.velocity.x = STOPPED;

    cursors.up.onDown.add(jump);
    if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        sprite.body.velocity.x = LEFT_VELOCITY
    }
    if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        sprite.body.velocity.x = RIGHT_VELOCITY;
    }

    if (sprite.isJumping && sprite.body.onFloor()) {
        sprite.isJumping = false;
        sprite.loadTexture("master");
        sprite.body.setSize(MASTER_WIDTH, MASTER_HEIGHT);
    }
}

function jump () {
    sprite.isJumping = true;
    sprite.body.velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY;

    sprite.loadTexture("phaser dude");
    sprite.body.setSize(PHASER_DUDE_WIDTH, PHASER_DUDE_HEIGHT);
}
```

You can see that if you push on the left side of the wall as the sprite changes size (and texture), it can move through the wall.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want users to usebug this, make them go back to the start of the wall if they are trying to go through it.
like this:

U is the user
|| is a wall

```
     ||
U    ||
     ||
     ||
```

The start

```
||
|U|
||
||
```

Oh, U is going through a wall !

```
  ||
U ||
  ||
  ||
```

U goes to the start of the wall.

or you can make the user unable to move while you change his size

EDIT:

there is two more solutions, set the walls with bounds system with a 0 value for bouncing:

```
function create () {
    game.add.text(TEXT_X_POS, TEXT_Y_POS, "Use the cursor keys to jump and move", {fontSize: "16px", fill: "white"});

    sprite = game.add.sprite(SPRITE_X_POS, SPRITE_Y_POS, "master");
    game.physics.arcade.enable(sprite);
    sprite.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    sprite.body.gravity.y = SPRITE_GRAVITY;

    wall = game.add.sprite(WALL_X_POS, WALL_Y_POS, "wall");
    game.physics.arcade.enable(wall);
    wall.body.immovable = true;
    //here is what i added
    wall.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    wall.body.bounce.set(0);

    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}
```

or make the sprite body immovble while you change his size:

```
function update () {
    game.physics.arcade.collide(sprite, wall);

    sprite.body.velocity.x = STOPPED;

    cursors.up.onDown.add(jump);
    if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        sprite.body.velocity.x = LEFT_VELOCITY
    }
    if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        sprite.body.velocity.x = RIGHT_VELOCITY;
    }
    if (sprite.isJumping && sprite.body.onFloor()) {
        sprite.isJumping = false;
        sprite.loadTexture("master");
        //Here is what i added
        sprite.body.velocity.x = STOPPED;
        sprite.body.setSize(MASTER_WIDTH, MASTER_HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the first solution that you proposed (the one where you put the user back in front of the wall if they go through it), but it looks kind of weird and I'm not sure if I want to use it just yet. Do you know of a way to "make the user unable to move while you change his size"?

Comment: can you please edit your post to add the code where you change user's size?

Comment: I made an edit to my post, so that there is an actual example of my problem and you can see the code that I'm using to change my user's size.

Comment: Are these two solutions working for you? I ask this because they don't seem to be working for me. Sorry, I hate to be a bother here, but I would still prefer having a better solution than solution number 1 (sticking the user outside of the wall when they overlap).

Comment: I couldn't test those solutions, but they should work, the second one is stopping the player before setting his size, i don't know how it can't work :s. Try to add a `console.log("Player stopped");`just after the code where you are supposed to stop him.
Maybe you should look for your solution <a href="examples.phaser.io">here</a>

Comment: I think that the second solution is not working because, even though it tells the player to stop, there's nothing keeping the player from starting again; all they have to do is press a key and the velocity will go back to normal. Also, thanks for sending me to examples.phaser.io, but I've already checked there for solutions.